# The foreign key usage/extra table

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I recently started looking into Database design. I have worked with Oracle, but would now like to create logical or conceptual design relationships first, before I implement them into the database. Learning the basics you could say.

I would like to create a database for cars. I have some tables, but am having trouble with the relationships, and when to use a foreign key/extra table.

I have created a car table, and added attributes. Now it is very clear to me to use a manufacturer foreign key in the car table referencing the manufacturer table. 
But for example I would like to show what type(SUV, sedan, etc.) the car is. Furthermore I would like to show What class(normal, Upperclass, etc.) the car is. Since I will only differentiate between a maximum of 5 car types, do I still need to add a foreign key? Same goes for the Class Situation as well. 
I have heard to always use a foreign key, because it safeguards the integrity of the database, but at University my teacher always told us to use the Minimum amount of tables as possible, therefore putting me in an awkward spot.

What should I do?

I would greatly appreciate clarification in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Even in toy systems, you should use foreign keys and extra tables; learning this habit will serve you well when the database gets larger, or when you start designing real databases.

I imagine that the remark about "minimum amount of tables" (should be "minimum number") is to prevent you creating tables containing two values (e.g. "yes" and "no", "present" and "not present"), again a good habit to learn. It could also refer to queries, where you do *not* want to join unnecessary tables; this is liable to lead to the query retrieving duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Car type and car class are examples of what is called an enumerated domain.  A domain is the set of values that an attribute may take on.  In Oracle terms it's the set of values that may be placed in a given column.  Oracle, unlike some other SQL dialects, does not have a CREATE DOMAIN statement.  You may be able to use CREATE TYPE instead but I can't tell you how.

The simplest solution for you may be to just create a lookup table, as you suggest.  Don't worry too much about added complexity here.

It is easier to manage 100 tables than 100,000 lines of code.  That's an old slogan from the dba world, but  it has some truth to it.